Victim loses internet connection during arp spoofing against it
The point is as follows.
VirtualBox is installed on my laptop. It has a Kali Linux virtual machine installed with which I want to perform ARP spoofing on my phone.
In the Kali Linux network settings, there is a Bridged networking in Adapter 1. Other adapters are turned off.
xxx.xxx.0.4 - Phone IP
xxx.xxx.0.1 - Router IP
I register it in the first Kali terminal:
echo 1 >  /procs/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
arpspoof -i eth0 -t xxx.xxx.0.4 xxx.xxx.0.1
In the second terminal:
arpspoof -i eth0 -t xxx.xxx.0.1 xxx.xxx.0.4
Everything seems to be as according to the book, however, when I try to open the website from my phone, it does not load. It just freezes and that's it. Tell me please how to solve the problem. Thanks.
p.s. Sorry for my English :D
I tried changing the connection settings in Adapter 1. I didn't touch the other adapters. I set NAT, NAT network. Nothing helped.

According to what book? Are you following class or teacher instructions possibly?
